# beamer and verbatimbox in multi language document

Tags: beamer, fontspec, verbatim

I need to place some text, as it is, with highlighting the first line, and other random such features. `verbatimbox` seems the right candidate. The document is a multilanguage one, using polyglossia.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\mode<presentsation>
%{\usetheme{metropolis}}  %<--- this changes the Mono font
                          % and \newfontfamily\englishfonttt{...}
                          % does not help. \setmonofont{...} must be used
                          % when needed (for verbatim e.g.)

\usepackage{polyglossia,verbatimbox,fontsize,ifthen}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifonttt[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{NotoSansDevanagari}

\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{NotoSans}

\newfontfamily\englishfonttt{NotoSansMono}[%
  UprightFont=*Regular,
  BoldFont=*Bold]

\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}
\newcommand{\engs}[1]{\scriptsizerrr{\textenglish{#1}}}
\newenvironment{engsenv}{%
  \setmonofont{NotoSansMono}
    \begin{english}
  }{%
    \end{english}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\newcommand*\ifline[3]{%
\ifthenelse{\value{VerbboxLineNo} = #1}{#2}{#3}}
  \newcommand*\highlight{\textbf}
\newcommand\nohighlight{\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1ex}}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\begin{verbbox}[\devanagarinumeral{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1mm}]
अ
आ
इ
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox       % works



\begin{engsenv}
  \begin{verbbox}[\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1mm}]
abc
def
ghi
  \end{verbbox}
\end{engsenv}
\theverbbox      % works



\begin{engsenv}
\begin{verbbox}[\ifline{1}{\highlight}{}]
jkl
mno
pqr
\end{verbbox}
\end{engsenv}
\theverbbox   % does not work



\begin{engsenv}
\begin{myverbbox}{\hibox}[\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1mm}]
stu
vwx
yza
\end{verbbox}
\end{engsenv}
\theverbbox      % doe not works

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Can you also describe what the content of your boxes is? Based on your previous comments, I wonder if they actually contain source code or if you are using them for something else?

Comment: The content is poetic verses, song lyrics. Here I did quickly something in loimpress. https://imgur.com/ixzQIri.png  . In the actual end result it will be a 2 column page. I'm going to use `tikz` for that, `verbatimbox` works well with it. One column in foreign script, the other in latin script.

Comment: actually, if it's not possible with `verbatimbox` I'll go for a custom obeylines done by a user in these forums.